# JS formatting date ymd to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am getting my date from `PHP` in format `ymd`. I am using `Moment.js` to convert it to format I need, but it's not working properly.

So for example today's date is comes like `190528` but after conversion to `YYYY-MM-DD` it becomes `190528-1-1` instead of `2019-05-28`.

Is it the first format of the date which causes the problem, or there is a way to overcome this and convert it the way I need?

Comment: How are you converting it? With Moment, you can pass a format string when parsing, `moment('190528', 'YYMMDD')` to parse it the way you want. Then you'll need to pass a format string when you want to actually format it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse Date first by passing format as 'YYMMDD'

```
moment("190528", "YYMMDD").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

This will give proper output.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the format of current date as a second param of moment.

```js
console.log(moment("190528", "YYMMDD").format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Here the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to load moment for this.

You can break the string into parts of years, month and date. Format the year and return the joined string...

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var _d = date.match(/.{1,2}/g);
  _d[0] = "20" + _d[0];
  return _d.join("-");
}
var d = "190528";
console.log(formatDate(d));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell moment what format your date string is in:

```js
console.log(moment("190528", "YYMMDD"))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```